# knife tool 2.8- used in past with no problems

Tags: knife-tool

[image: modeling tab][image: layout tab] Vertices are not appearing when I drag with the knife tool across the object in edit mode. Am I missing a toggle somewhere? I would include a picture/screenshot but wouldn't really show you anything except knife hovering above the object.  I have used this tool with no problem before and I am thinking maybe there is something disabled that is critical to the tool.

Comment: Perhaps you're in face select mode? Better add the screenshot, maybe we see something that you didn't notice.

Comment: yes it looks like there's not the little green squares that snaps to the vertex if that's what you're talking about?

Comment: No. I am in vertex mode.  Tried it again and works if I go to modeling tab.  Once again, makes me think it is a toggle somewhere.

Comment: Why work in modeling tab and not layout?

Comment: Well, chalk it up to the mysteries of blender.  I will just go to the modeling tab if I need to use the knife tool.  Thanks for trying guys.  If anyone can shed some light as to why this is happening, I would love to know.  Thanks again all.

Answer (score 1):

In blender 2.8, the knife function does not work in view clip start 0.001, try to fix it to 0.01.

[image: screen]

Comment: Tried clip start .001 and .01. does not affect in layout tab. thanks anyway though.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. If it still hasn't been fixed, why don't you [file a bug report](https://developer.blender.org/) and see what the developers say?